# Jquery script crashes

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
function manChecks() {
    if ($("#__CS").length > 0) {
        var cols = $("#__CS").val();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            colManage(i, cols.indexOf('|' + i) != -1);
        }
    }
}
```

So what happens if that code is less than 0 it shouldn't run - but it seems to be causing an issue.

Have a written this correctly or have I missed something.

Comment: what error do you gets ?

Comment: always check your web console when having js issues. `tools->web developer->web console` or `ctrl+shift+k` in firefox

Comment: The question is not very clear in what you're doing and trying to accomplish. Maybe you could create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ and add the necessary html and js to demonstrate your problem. As it is now, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: What kind of element is `$("#__CS")`, maybe it doesn't match to be used by `length`. Try to use `count` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code currently does:

- If `#__CS` does not exist in the document, do nothing (this check will not cause an error)
- If `#__CS` does exist, its `.val()` will be set to `cols`. This will never cause an error.
- After that, you will iterate from 1 – 9. This will not cause your code to break.
- Nine times, `colManage` will be called, passing a value from 1 to 9, together with an indication of whether or not `|1` to `|9` exists in the string `cols`. This call will never cause your code to break either, but something in `colManage` could very well cause it to break.